# Interactive console in Eclipse, any way to make it more interactive?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is there any way to use more interactive console than the one already available? Right now, I can run console and check whether everything is working fine but when I make a change to code I need to terminate existing console and create new one - this is really painful when making small changes.

Another problem I have is that when I run console for open code I still need to import functions(and lists) in order to test them. This coupled with the fact that I need to restart console every time doesn't make for a pleasant working environment. Is there any way to import code into console completely(automaticaly) when initialising it?

Maybe there is easier way to write and test python code?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% related to Eclise but I think it's a good suggestion in general.

Use python unittest library, write your test you want your code pass like this

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_some_code(self):
        import a
        import b
        ... lots of lines that i need to prep the whole thing...
        works = "my_expected_results!"
        self.assertEqual(myfunction(**params), works)
```

this way you just iterate edits and test runs (using the eclipse "run as python unittest")

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't answer my question, I'm not having problems with testing in general but testing within console environment.